# VC++ loop until button pressed

Tags: events, visual-c++, button, loops

On button1_Click I call method DoStuff();

```
DoStuff()
{
  //how to make a loop within this method that pauses when I click button2 ?
  SomeCodeToLoop();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move this doStuff code into another thread. When you press the button2 either pause the thread or use some [events](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/552/Using-Worker-Threads) to signal the thread to wait until the event is signaled.